Evento Cellclick de datagridview genera error al devolver valores nulos en vb.net
Utilizo un datagridview con propiedad SelectionMode en FullRowSelect, uso el evento cellclick para rellenar textbox de datos pero al seleccionar una fila que contenga datos nulos devuelve el siguiente error: System.InvalidCastException: 'La conversión del tipo 'DBNull' en el tipo 'String' no es válida.'
Este es mi codigo del evento CellClick
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = TryCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If dgv IsNot Nothing AndAlso dgv.SelectedCells.Count > 0 Then
        Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = dgv.SelectedCells(0)
        If row IsNot Nothing Then
            txtcodigo.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value
            txtdescrip.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(1).Value
            txtubic.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(2).Value
            txtp1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(3).Value
            txtp2.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(4).Value
            txtp3.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(5).Value
            txtpdiv1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(6).Value
            txtpdiv2.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(7).Value
            txtpdiv3.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(8).Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Cabe destacar que me guie por el codigo muy similar que uso para el evento Selection changed, en el cual no tengo ningun tipo de errores:
    Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = TryCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If dgv IsNot Nothing AndAlso dgv.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgv.SelectedRows(0)
        If row IsNot Nothing Then
            txtcodigo.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            txtdescrip.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
            txtubic.Text = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
            txtp1.Text = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
            txtp2.Text = row.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
            txtp3.Text = row.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
            txtpdiv1.Text = row.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
            txtpdiv2.Text = row.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
            txtpdiv3.Text = row.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
        End If
    End If

End Sub


Sin tener mucha idea de vb.net, se aprecia una diferencia sustancial que parece relacionada con el mensaje de error, ese "ToString()" que aparece en el código de abajo pero no en el de arriba.

Tienes algun valor en las celdas que es NULL y la estás intentando convertir a string, esto genera el error al parecer.
